# PHP: changing DPI of an image using imagick?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to increase an image DPI using PHP and imagic.

However, everytime I use the following code, my page returns a 500 error!

this is the code:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(300,300);
$im->readImage("test.png");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
```

I know image magic is installed as I am using a VPS and I also tried this code which works fine:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/convert bb9yuui70.png -bordercolor black -border 10x10 bb9yuui70.png");
?>
<img src="bb9yuui70.png">
```

Is there something that i am missing? I am quite new to the world of imagic.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500 server error → Take a look at webserver errors log<sup>1</sup> and you will see:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

or

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object'...

If you see the first error, you have to install [`Imagick`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) php module (it is not enough to have `imagemagick` installed).

But, also with `Imagick` installed, your code fails, because you have **first** to load the image, **then** to set units, resolution, etc...

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage("test.png");                                   # <--------
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(300,300);
$im->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, two above errors can also be displayed without looking at webserver logfile: next time, place `ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); error_reporting( E_ALL );` at top of your script and you will see the most errors directly on your page (then, remove it on production).